# Двойной вызов конструктора с std::initializer_list

Tags: c++, конструктор, инициализация, конструктор-копирования

Почему следующая программа

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>


template<typename T>
struct A {
    A(std::initializer_list<T> list) {
        std::cout << "list" << '\n';
    }

    A(const A& a) {
        std::cout << "copy" << '\n';
    }

    A& operator=(const A& a) {
        std::cout << "copy assignment" << '\n';

        return *this;
    }

    A& operator=(A&& a) noexcept {
        std::cout << "move assignment" << '\n';

        return *this;
    }
};


int main() {
    A<int> a{};
    auto b = A{a,a};
}
```

выводит

> list
>
> copy
>
> copy
>
> list

?

Comment: Лично у меня этот код даже не компилируется - выводит `error: missing template arguments before '{' token`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А что тут неясно?

Первая строка - при создании `a`, вторая - при подготовке инициализатора для `b` - копирование двух `a`, третья - при создании `b` из списка инициализации...

Comment: двух 'а'  или  а двух его копий ?

Comment: Почему `b` создается не копирующим конструктором?

Comment: По сути ваша запись с `b` ничем не отличается от `A<A<int>,A<int>> b{a,a}` - тут копирования не видно...

Answer (score 1):

```
здесь
int main() {
A<int> a{};
auto b = A{a,a};
}

происходит следующее:
строка   A<int> a{};  - создается лист а, при этом 
         вызывается A(std::initializer_list<T> list) {std::cout << "list" << '\n';}
               выводится "list"
строка   auto b = A{a,a};  - создается лист листов, в который 2 раза добавляется 
                             созданный в предидущей строке а, 
                             так как созданный а - это A<int> (лист)
         поэтому 
            дважды вызывается A(const A& a) {std::cout << "copy" << '\n';}
              при создании 2-х а для A{a,a}
               выводится "copy", "copy"                             
            затем вызывается 
              A(std::initializer_list<T> list) {std::cout << "list" << '\n';}
              при создании самого A{a,a}, который является листом
               выводится "list"
```

Comment: Если обьект констрируется  при помщи  списка инициализации( лист ), это не знчит, что он тоже становится таким же списком(листом), и никакого лист листов тут нет

Comment: изложите пожалуйста Вашу версию, почему получается именно такой вывод?) я не претендую на абсолютные знания в этом вопросе) увидела только такое объяснение, буду благодарна, если Вы поможете разобраться в этом лучше)

Comment: Участники, в том числе и я, обязаны  указать на ошибку в ответе. Тут нет причин обижаться.  Нет тут никаких версий, тут есть один точный ответ, который вы можете прочитать  в другом ответе, и мне незачем повторять то же самое...

Comment: спасибо) сейчас посмотрю) никаких обид) наоборот, благодарна, что уделили внимание и ответили)